# Auto Path in Dokapon Kingdom - how do they do it?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

In the video game *Dokapon Kingdom* ([here's an example video on it](https://youtu.be/FZm_95nNhRI)), the objective is to go around saving towns while simultaneously screwing over your friends (who will no longer be your friends). (It's been described as "*Mario Party* meets an RPG".)

Prominently featured within that game is the Auto Path function, which determines what spaces are reachable from the current space using a path of length $n$, namely, what the player rolled. Said path can loop multiple times, and can even end up turning around on itself, but it cannot traverse the same edge twice in a row (i.e. no sudden U-turns).

Translating the game board to a graph (and its associated adjacency matrix) is very easy, but how does one enforce the no sudden U-turns rule? Using the squared matrix with its diagonal zeroed out doesn't work, as that still allows a U-turn after every other edge taken.

Comment: Depending on how long these paths are, they might just compute them all using some search algorithm

Comment: The video you link to is 13 minutes long. Can you give a timestamp to the part where it shows the mechanic you're talking about?

Comment: @HenningMakholm 6:33 is the first time it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a different graph where each node is labeled by the combination of "where you are" and "which edge you have just arrived by"; then iterate it $n$ times.

Comment: Is it that efficient for the hypothetical maximum possible roll of 30 (by using a 5 Spinner)? That's a lot of branches that would have to be taken care of.